# Function Reference/wp insert post 'post_category'

Tags: php, wordpress

Reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post

If you see the above link, it is clearly said that you can Category ID in wp_insert_post:

```
'post_category'  => [ array(<category id>, ...) ] // Default empty.
```

But i want to add variable

```
$cat=Samsung; //keep on changing
'post_category' => $cat;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use get_cat_ID (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_cat_ID)

If it's just one category:

```
$cat=get_cat_ID( 'Samsung' );
'post_category' => array($cat)
```

Otherwise you will need to do a foreach and create the array.

Answer (score 0):

It's fine to use a variable. As per the line you quote, the category should be an array of category ids. So in your example, you should try:

```
'post_category' => array($cat)
```

Comment: I think this answer is outdated, no ID necessary... "(array) Array of category names, slugs, or IDs. Defaults to value of the 'default_category' option."